# Is it legal to use "VMware Workstation 15 Player" with earning money purpose?

Tags: blog, legal

I am planning to open a blog webpage, publish technology-based content on it and make money via blogger earning methods like Google AdSense. The software I mentioned in the title, which is available at [here](https://www.vmware.com/tr/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html), is just one of the necessities to prepare my content.

However, firstly, I want to be sure whether this kind of usage is legal or not for this software. When I look at the link I added, there is an expression in the form of "The free version is available for non-commercial, personal and home use."

According to this statement, is it legal for me to use this software as I have stated?

Comment: From what I know, it is legal, so you should have no problems with it.

Comment: @Roberterop, if you read the page the link refers to, you would see that it permission is sis *not* granted to commercial use.  I.e.,  "free version is available for non-commercial, personal and home use".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will be earning using the software, it automatically falls into commercial use, so its not.